# JQuery does not run the asp.net backend method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I made this JQuery script. It runs when btnEliminar is clicked. It runs thru a table getting the selected rows and adds the Id of every selected into an array of Jsons. Everything works as expected until AJAX runs. The backend method doesnt executes, I know this because execution doesn't stop when I set a breakpoint there. What am I doing wrong? -- I'm new with JQuery

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnEliminar').on('click', function () {
        var sel = obtenerSeleccionados(); //gets ids of selected rows
        var listaIds = [];
        $.each(sel, function (key, value) {
            listaIds.push({ id: value }); //turns data as Json
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "frmBancoPreguntas.aspx/eliminarPreguntas",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "{}",
            data: JSON.stringify(listaIds),
            success: function (response) {
            },
            error: function (response) {
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Backend method:

```
    <WebMethod()> _ //imported System.Web.Services
    Public Shared Sub eliminarPreguntas(ByVal listaIds As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Integer)))
        Try
            For Each d As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) In listaIds
                gestorP.eliminarPregunta(d.Item("id"))
            Next
        Catch ex As DataAccessException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString)
        Catch ex As BusinessLogicException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim x As New PresentationLayerException("Ha ocurrido un error al eliminar una pregunta", ex)
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Check your console for errors, but I'd assume it's because of the `dataType: "{}"` in your Ajax call. I don't believe that is a correct Data Type. - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Have you tried replacing dataType: "{}" with dataType: "json" ?